# Запуск MX плеера с плейлистом на Android 4.0.4

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, firemonkey, android

Здравствуйте!

Моя задача запустить МХ плеер с плейлистом, но как это сделать, я не знаю, прошу помощи.

Вот код запуска видеофайла. При запуске следующего видео предыдущее воспроизведение убивается, но мне нужно запустить с плейлистом в определёной последовательсти, как это сделать? Прошу помощи.

Есть ссылка на апи плеера и описание запуска с плейлистом:
https://sites.google.com/site/mxvpen/api

```
procedure TForm1.Play(const sFileName: string);
var
  PackageName: Jstring;
  ActiveManager: JActivityManager;
  sFile, exe: string;
  Intent: JIntent;
  Data: Jnet_Uri;
begin
  try
    sFile := sFileName;
    // MX player: https://sites.google.com/site/mxvpen/api
    PackageName := StringToJString('com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad');
    ActiveManager := GetActivityManager();
    ActiveManager.killBackgroundProcesses(PackageName);
    exe := System.IOUtils.TPath.GetExtension(sFile);
    Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
    Data := StrToJURI(sFile);
    Intent.setDataAndType(Data, StringToJString(PWideChar('video/') + exe));
    Intent.setPackage(PackageName);
    Intent.addFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or
      TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    SharedActivity().startActivity(Intent);
  finally
  end;
end;
```